# Is it more performant to use a JOIN or a when using LIMIT 1?

Tags: mysql

I have a products table. I want to select all fields (of a given row) and the most profitable discount that the user can claim (depends on ordered quantity of the product).

When selecting only one value only, is it more performant to use a JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT p.*, qd.price AS qd_price

FROM products AS p

-- Find all applicable QDs
LEFT OUTER JOIN quantity_discounts as qd
    ON p.id=qd.product_id
    AND qd.min_amount <= ?
    AND (
        (qd.user_id IS NULL OR qd.user_id = 0 OR qd.user_id = ?)
        OR (qd.group_id IS NULL OR qd.group_id = 0 OR qd.group_id = ?)
    )

WHERE p.id=?

-- Get the lowest QD price
ORDER BY qd.price ASC
LIMIT 1
```

or a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT p.*,
(SELECT price FROM quantity_discounts
WHERE product_id=p.id
AND (
    (user_id=? or user_id=0 or user_id IS NULL)
    OR (group_id=? or group_id=0 or group_id IS NULL)
)
AND qd.min_amount <= ?
ORDER BY price LIMIT 1) AS qd_price
FROM products as p
WHERE p.id=?
```

Comment: Why don’t you test the two and answer your own question? It’s allowed, encouraged even.

Comment: If you do post an answer, be sure to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, so the indexes (if any) are clear.  Be sure to avoid the Query cache, and run twice to avoid other caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORs` are deadly for performance.  For starters, decide on `0` or `NULL` so you won't have to test for both.  (That won't actually help any since there would still be other `ORs`.)

I'm dubious about the formulation of the `LEFT JOIN`.  (BTW, `OUTER` is optional.)  Normally when using `LEFT`, the `ON` only says how the tables are related (`p.id=qd.product_id`); the `WHERE` provides the filtering.

I don't know which is better, but since you seem to be limiting to one `id` (via `WHERE p.id=?`), then the second formulation will look into `quantity_discounts` only once, and (hopefully) won't have too many rows to check.  That is, the `OR` may not be as bad as I started out with.

A slight help on `quantity_discounts` will be

```
INDEX(product_id, price)  -- in this order
```

Now I am worried.  One formulation has `AND qd.min_amount <= ?`, the other does not.

Comment: > *The ORs are deadly for performance. For starters, decide on 0 or NULL* 0 is the value the app sets, NULL is the default. I'll set it to NOT NULL with a default. Thanks for pointing out the lack of `min_amount`, I'll fix the query in the question. I took it from another part of the code where only the existence of a `qd_price` matters. FWIW, it could be named `qd_exists`. I think the `INDEX` won't do anything in my case, since I'm using a PK constraint https://imgur.com/a/N9FAeSV

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich - Both versions allow for there being no `qd_price`.  I don't understand what you mean about `qd_exists`.  And what is the point of the imgur?  Is it what to put in the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Right, price is not part of the PK constraint, so it makes sense to use INDEX. Ignore the imgur then. I meant that I took the other code from a function which only uses `qd_price` to check if it's not null. It doesn't actually need the price, so the purpose of it in the second query (in my code) is if the QD exists, which is why the second query lacks the `qd.min_amount <= ?`.